# Use Javascript to move players to form and remove from form

Tags: javascript, python, html

I need to be able to move over the player.gamer_tag value to the form, disable the button so they cannot be added again, and a button to remove them from the form.

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUfiN.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="box" id="players">
                <!-- table
                Gamertag    Team    PPG Value somesortofsubmitbutton
                -->
                <h3>Player Pool</h3>
                <table style="width: 80%;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Gamertag</th>
                        <th>Team</th>
                        <th>PPG</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for player in playerList %}
                        <tr>
                            <td id="gamerTag">{{ player.gamer_tag }}</td>
                            <td id="team">{{ player.team }}</td>
                            <td id="fppg">{{ player.fppg }}</td>
                            <td id="value">{{ player.value }}</td>
                            <td><button id="selectButton" style="background-color: green;" onclick="addPlayer('{{ player.gamer_tag }}')">Select</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <!-- try using regular html form, post method, grab on python side, may have to let users type until automation
             make input boxes required and use javascript to check for empties-->
            <h3>Lineup</h3>
            <form id="form1" method="POST" action="/lineup-creation">
                <input type="text" id="captain" required placeholder="Captain"><br>
                <input type="text" id="player1" required placeholder="Flex"><br>
                <input type="text" id="player2" required placeholder="Flex"><br>
                <input type="text" id="player3" required placeholder="Flex"><br>
                <input type="text" id="player4" required placeholder="Flex"><br>
                <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit Lineup</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addPlayer(gamerTag)
    {
        document.getElementById("captain").value = gamerTag;
        document.getElementById("selectButton")[0].setAttribute("disabled", disabled");
    }
    /*$(document).on('click', ':button', function(e){
        var btn = $(e.target);
        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });*/
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure why the javascript function is not added to the code sample.

Comment: At the beginning there were two `<div>`s at the same level, but the outer `</div>` got unindented completely and the code format was applied only because it continued from the previous lines. Then came an empty line before the `<script>` tag, and separation of blocks jumped in, code formatting restarted.